# QListWidget : Event on item click

Tags: c++, qt

Basically, what I have is the following :

A QListWidget, with some items in it like this :

`ListMail` is my QListWidget.
In this QListWidget, I have elements like : "Mail 1", "Mail 2", ...

And I don't have any idea, how can I make a signal on (for example) "Mail 1" bind to a slot(onClick) or something like that.

I already tried things like :
`connect(ui->listMail->selectedItems(0), SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(openMessage())`, but it doesn't work at all...

Any help ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You must bind to the [`itemClicked`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlistwidget.html#itemClicked) signal. The signal will provide you with a `QListWidgetItem*` which is the item that was clicked. You can then examine it and check if it is the first one:

```
MyClass::MyClass(QWidget* parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    connect(ui->listMail, SIGNAL(itemClicked(QListWidgetItem*)), 
            this, SLOT(onListMailItemClicked(QListWidgetItem*)));
}

void MyClass::onListMailItemClicked(QListWidgetItem* item)
{
    if (ui->listMail->item(0) == item) {
        // This is the first item.
    }
}
```

Comment: I should have also explained why passing a `QListWidgetItem` to `connect` did not work: since it does not extend `QObject` it cannot emit signals (or have slots).

Comment: I don't know why but for me (i'm using PyQt version 5.7.1) `itemClicked` did not work - no signal was sent. But when changing to `itemPressed` there was no problem

Comment: @sunyata You're using a touch interface, perhaps?

Comment: @andref You would think so but no, i'm running on Lubuntu 16.04 LTS on my laptop and i've used a usb mouse (also tried with the left-click button below the touchpad). However there is some strange behaviour because sometimes when i click the signal *is* sent, but this happens only maybe one out of ten times. In any case i just wanted to post this here in case anyone else runs into the same thing

Answer (score 2):

QListWidget has a signal `QListWidget::itemPressed(QListWidgetItem *item)` that will tell you which item was clicked. You can connect this signal to your own slot. There are also other related signals. See the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html).