# Get clicked item from QListWidget and QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt

I need to read an item from both QTableWidged and Q ListWidget as the user clicks on them.

For QListWidget I tried the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311241/qlistwidget-event-on-item-click), however the used `SIGNAL itemClicked` never seems to trigger.

For QTableWidget I tried multiple solutions, however they either didn't work or weren't what I need. Is there a simple solution for QTableWidget and am I just overlooking something with the solution provided for QListWidget?

Edit:

My Constructor of my MainWindow.cpp looks like this:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
                                      QMainWindow(parent),
                                      ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
     ui->setupUi(this);


     ui->TableWidget->verticalHeader()->setVisible(true);

     QTableWidget* table = ui->TableWidget;

     connect(ui->listWidget, SIGNAL(itemClicked(QListWidgetItem*)),
         this,   SLOT(showBuchungsDetails(parseListWidgetBuchung(QListWidgetItem*))));

     QHeaderView *header = qobject_cast<QTableView *>(table)->horizontalHeader();
     connect(header, &QHeaderView::sectionClicked, [this](int logicalIndex){
         QString text = ui->TableWidget->horizontalHeaderItem(logicalIndex)->text();
         ui->lnBuchungsnummer->setText(text);

     });

}
```

And here is my header file for MainWindow:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QListWidget>
#include "TravelAgency.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_actionDatei_einlesen_triggered();

    void on_actionProgramm_beenden_triggered();

    void on_actionBuchungen_anzeigen_triggered();

    Customer* parseListWidgetBuchung(QListWidgetItem* item);

    Customer* parseTableWidgetBuchung(QString item);

    void showBuchungsDetails(Customer* c);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    TravelAgency travelagency{};
    bool inputReady = false;
    QStringList m_TableHeader;

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Edit 2:
I am using Qt Creator 4.8.2

Comment: I honestly don't know what kind of example you expect. I have get the row the user clicked in the QTableWidget and I have to get the item the user clicked on in the ListWidget. I tried to use the connect function to link the SIGNAL both Widgets are supposed to send out to a function of my own, but that doesn't seem to work. The only interesting thing is that I used both connect functions in the constructor of my MainWindow, but that's it.

Comment: The correct form is the itemClicked signal so if it does not work it is probably on the other hand of your code, so if you want help you should provide an MCVE, if you do not know what it is then read the content of the link

Comment: Still not MCVE. In the meantime some suggestions: you can enable or disable the vertical header in the Designer's Property Editor; I'd convert the old-style connection with SIGNAL and SLOT macros to new style as in your second connection, you get compile-time checking;  and why do you use this `qobject_cast`? `auto header = table->horizontalHeader()` should work without the cast.

Comment: @replete He uses Qt 4.8.2, the new-style connection is not available

Comment: @Fabio He uses Creator 4.8.2, not Qt 4.8.2. He obviously uses Qt5 because the second `connect` in his example is in the new style.

Comment: @replete Whoops!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions, but I managed to sidestep the ´connect´ syntax completely by rightclicking on the widgeds in question on my UI window and use the "Go to slot..." functionality to create

```
void MainWindow::on_listWidget_itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item)
{
    parseListWidgetBuchung(item);
}

void MainWindow::on_TableWidget_cellClicked(int row, int column)
{
    parseTableWidgetBuchung(ui->TableWidget->item(row, 0)->text());
}
```

which then allowed me to get the respective items. Either way, thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Do not use the `SLOT`/`SIGNAL` syntax for C++ signals and slots. This is error prone, since mistakes like this are not caught during compilation. Your code compiles fine but doesn't work.

Use Qt5 connect syntax. In this case, you can use a lambda:

```
connect(ui->listWidget, &QListWidget::itemClicked, this, [this](QListWidgetItem* item)
{
    showBuchungsDetails(parseListWidgetBuchung(item));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `connect` call is wrong. If you use the SIGNAL - SLOT syntax, the slot must be a single function (it's a "reference" to the function).

You can do something like this:

```
connect(ui->listWidget, SIGNAL(itemClicked(QListWidgetItem*)),
         this,   SLOT(onItemClicked(QListWidgetItem*)));
```

And the `onItemClicked` implementation:

```
void MainWindow::onItemClicked(QListWidgetItem* item)
{
   showBuchungsDetails(parseListWidgetBuchung(item));
}
```